# Calcular Quantidade x Preço e jogar valor em input e sessão

Tags: php

Estou tentando jogar um calculo de total em um input e também em sessão em carrinho de compra que estou desenvolvendo e não estou conseguindo, tentarei explicar o problema que tenho.

Os inputs estão assim:

```
<div class="qty">

// QUANTIDADE
<?php if ( isset($_SESSION["quantidade"][$id]) && ($_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] != 0) ){ ?>
<input type="text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] ?>" id_qtd="<?php echo $list['id_produto'] ?>"  />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="<?php echo $QTD; ?>" class="input" id_qtd="<?php echo $list['id_produto']; ?>" />
<?php }  ?>&nbsp; x &nbsp;

// VALOR UNITÁRIO
<?php if ( isset($_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id]) && ($_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] != 0) ){ ?>
<input type="text" id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario" maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] ?>" id_unit="<?php echo $list['id_produto'] ?>"  />
<?php } else { ?>
<input type="text" id="valor_unitario" name="valor_unitario" value="<?php echo $QTD; ?>" class="input" id_unit="<?php echo $list['id_produto']; ?>" />
<?php }  ?>&nbsp; = &nbsp;                                      

SOMA TOTAL
<input type="text" id="valor_total" name="valor_total" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["valor_total"][$id]; ?>" 
id_total="<?php echo $list['id_produto']; ?>" />
```

Cada registro, como `quantidade` e `valor unitário`estou guardando em sessão e eles ficam registrados mesmo quando insiro um novo produto, faço isso para guarda-los:

As chamadas estão assim:

```
        // ATUALIZANDO QUANTIDADE
        $("input[name='quantidade']").blur(function(){  

            var sAcao = 'atualizar-quantidade';
            var sQuantidade = $(this).val();
            var sID_QTD = $(this).attr('id_qtd');           

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "atualizar-dados.php",             

                data: {
                    'acao' : sAcao,
                    'quantidade' : sQuantidade,
                    'id_qtd' : sID_QTD
                },              

                success: function(msg){
                    $(".ms").text(msg);
                }               
            });
        });

        // ATUALIZANDO O VALOR UNITÁRIO
        $("input[name='valor_unitario']").blur(function(){  

            var sAcaoUnit = 'atualizar-valor';
            var sValorUnitario = $(this).val();
            var sID_UNI = $(this).attr('id_unit');  

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "atualizar-valor.php",             

                data: {
                    'acaoUnit' : sAcaoUnit,
                    'valor_unitario' : sValorUnitario,
                    'id_unit' : sID_UNI
                },              

                success: function(msg){
                    $(".ms").text(msg);
                }               
            });
        }); 

    });
```

Quantidade:

```
    session_start();
    $acaoUnit = $_POST['acao'];

    if ( isset($acao) && $acao == 'atualizar-quantidade' ){
        $id = isset($_POST["id_qtd"]) ? $_POST["id_qtd"] : null;

        $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] = $_POST['quantidade'];
        //echo $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id];    
    }
```

Valor Unitário:

```
    session_start();
    $acaoUnit = $_POST['acaoUnit'];

    if ( isset($acaoUnit) && $acaoUnit == 'atualizar-valor' ){
        $id = isset($_POST["id_unit"]) ? $_POST["id_unit"] : null;

        $_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] = $_POST['valor_unitario'];
        // echo $_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id];   
    }
```

O que estou tentando fazer para guardar a soma total:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $("input[name='valor_total']").focus(function() {

        $('.qty').each(function() {

            // console.log(this);

            var qtd = $(this).find('input[name=quantidade]').val()
            var val = $(this).find('input[name=valor_unitario]').val();         

            // QUANTIDADE TOTAL
            var total = parseFloat(qtd) * parseFloat(val);              

            $(this).find('input[name=valor_total]').val(total); 

            var sAcaoTotal = 'atualizar-total';
            var sValorTotal = total;
            // var sID_Total = $(this).attr('id_total');    

            // alert(sValorTotal);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "atualizar-total.php",             

                data: {
                    'acaoTotal' : sAcaoTotal,
                    'valor_total' : sValorTotal
                    // 'id_total' : sID_Total
                },              

                success: function(msg){
                    $(".ms").text(msg);
                }   

            });



        });
    })
}
```

E a tentativa de guardar o valor em sessão:

```
    session_start();

    $acaoTotal = $_POST['acaoTotal'];

    if ( isset($acaoTotal) && $acaoTotal == 'atualizar-total' ){

        $id = isset($_POST["id_total"]) ? $_POST["id_total"] : null;

        $_SESSION["valor_total"][$id] = $_POST['valor_total'];
        // echo $_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id];   
    }
```

Para a quantidade e valor unitário funciona, mas para o total não, ele está fazendo o seguinte:
Insiro um novo produto, informa a quantidade e valor unitário e ao clicar no campo de total a soma é feita, mas ao inserir um novo produto o total some, mas se clicar no campo total o valor é calculado.
Espero não ter complicado.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não consegui entender o que quis dizer, eu penso em umas soluções já, porem, para ter certeza, gostaria que explicasse melhor

Comment: Olá @RafaelAugusto, preciso guardar o valor total, não consigo ficar com ele disponível, a quantidade e valor unitário permanecem, mas o valor total não.

Comment: Pode ser com JS?

Comment: Se me ajudar @RafaelAugusto, está valendo.

Comment: Vou te dar a ideia pra você salvar, se você achar que funciona no seu caso (pois não entendi muito bem para ter certeza), posto uma resposta completa. Já pensou em usar `sessionStorage` ou `localStorage`? você armazena o valor e pode buscalo a qualquer montento, em qualquer pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar próprio PHP em cada atualização de valor e quantidade unitários para persistir o total na sessão, poupando inclusive a chamada AJAX extra para o valor_total, já que ele muda sempre que um dos outros dois é alterado:

**Quantidade e total:**

```
session_start();
$acaoUnit = $_POST['acao'];

if ( isset($acao) && $acao == 'atualizar-quantidade' ){
    $id = isset($_POST["id_qtd"]) ? $_POST["id_qtd"] : null;

    $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] = $_POST['quantidade'];
    $_SESSION["valor_total"][$id] = ($_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] *  $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id]);
}
```

**Valor unitário e total:**

```
session_start();
$acaoUnit = $_POST['acaoUnit'];

if ( isset($acaoUnit) && $acaoUnit == 'atualizar-valor' ){
    $id = isset($_POST["id_unit"]) ? $_POST["id_unit"] : null;

    $_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] = $_POST['valor_unitario'];
    $_SESSION["valor_total"][$id] = ($_SESSION["valor_unitario"][$id] * $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id]);
}
```

Dessa forma você pode retornar tanto o valor alterado (quantidade ou valor unitário) quanto o valor total para a mesma chamada AJAX do input e tratar os dois ao mesmo tempo no javascript.

Comment: Olá @nunks.lol, bom dia, fiz o indicado e ainda não consegui resolver, valeu pela dica.